# Is my output of librosa MFCC correct? I think I get the wrong number of frames when using librosa MFCC

Tags: python, audio, librosa, audio-processing, mfcc

```
result=librosa.feature.mfcc(signal, 16000, n_mfcc=13, n_fft=2048, hop_length=400)
result.shape()
```

The signal is 1 second long with sampling rate of 16000, I compute 13 MFCC with 400 hop length. The output dimensions are `(13,41)`. Why do I get 41 frames, isn't it supposed to be `(time*sr/hop_length)=40`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR answer

Yes, it is correct.

### Long answer

You are using a time-series as input (`signal`), which means that *librosa* first computes a mel spectrogram using the [melspectrogram](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html#librosa.feature.melspectrogram) function. It takes a bunch of arguments, of which you have already specified one (`n_fft`). It's important to note that [melspectrogram](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html#librosa.feature.melspectrogram) also offers the two parameters `center` and `pad_mode` with the default values `True` and `"reflect"` respectively.

From the docs:

> **pad_mode: string:**
> If center=True, the padding mode to use at the edges of the signal.
> By default, STFT uses reflection padding.

> **center: boolean:**
> If True, the signal y is padded so that frame t is centered at y[t * hop_length].
> If False, then frame t begins at y[t * hop_length]

In other words, by default, *librosa* makes your signal longer (pads) in order to support centering.

If you'd like to avoid this behavior, you should to pass `center=False` to your `mfcc` call.

That all said, when setting `center` to `False`, keep in mind that with an `n_fft` length of 2048 and a hop length of `400`, you don't necessarily get `(time*sr/hop_length)=40` frames, because you have to also account for the *window* and not just the *hop* length (unless you pad somehow). Hop length just specifies by how many samples you move that window.

To give an extreme example, consider a very large window and a very short hop length: Assume 10 samples (e.g. `time=1s`, `sr=10Hz`), a window length of `n_fft=9` and `hop_length=1` with `center=False`. Now imagine sliding the window over the 10 samples.

```
   ◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◻︎
   ◻︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎◼︎
t  0123456789

◻︎ sample not covered by window
◼︎ sample covered by window
```

At first the window starts at `t=0` and ends at `t=8`. How many times can we shift it by `hop_length` and still expect it to not run out of samples? Exactly once, until it starts at `t=1` and ends at `t=9`. Add the first unshifted one and you arrive at 2 frames. This is obviously different from the incorrect `(time*sr/hop_length)=1*10/1=10`.

Correct would be: `(time*sr-n_fft)//hop_length+1=(1*10-9)//1+1=2` with `//` denoting Python-style integer division.

When using the default, i.e. `center=True`, the signal is padded with `n_fft // 2` samples on both ends, so `n_fft` falls out of the equation.

Comment: Are you aware why I get 41 ? It seems the number of frames is always ((time*sr/hop_length))+1. No matter the (nfft) passed.

Comment: When `center=True`, *librosa* pads with `n_fft // 2` samples on either end. So in essence, `n_fft` does have no effect on the number of frames. But with `center=False`, that's not the case and you have to take `n_fft` into account. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: @Hendrik can you explain on how **window** cause the number of frames to be 41 by showing a calculation example?

Comment: I didn't write that the *window* length causes the number of frames to be 41. I just wrote that, if you turn `center` off, you have to take the window length into account.