# Why does librosa.feature.melspectrogram return a output of length math.trunc(sample length/hop_length)+1?

Tags: python, librosa

I am trying to understand why librosa.feature.melspectrogram returns an output shape that isn't simply sample length/hop_length.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is my output of librosa MFCC correct? I think I get the wrong number of frames when using librosa MFCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68214065/is-my-output-of-librosa-mfcc-correct-i-think-i-get-the-wrong-number-of-frames-w)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.