# python - understanding librosa.stft output shape

Tags: python, librosa

Why does `lengthofinputsamples/hop_length` not equal to the `stft's` output 2nd dimension. Instead, I noticed that the `stft's` output was equal to `ceil(lengthofinputsamples/hop_length)`. Why is this?

In my instance:

```
sgram = np.abs(librosa.stft(samples,n_fft=2048,hop_length=512,center=True))
```

`returns 21189` when the input samples length is equal to `10848704`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68216475/942774